# Android Studio 2.3 rc1 App Crashes and Empty Log

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, release-candidate

I've installed Android Studio 2.3 rc1 and my app doesn't run. Only the Splash screen activity that I've setted up is shown, and then the app crashes. 
The big problem is that the **log is empty**, shows only "Connected to process..." and "Application terminated".

How can I solve this? Is it normal for non-stable version of Android Studio (I'm a noob) or it's a problem of my app?

**Edit 1:** I've tried to create a new simple project but the result is the same. So maybe the problem is the IDE.

**Edit 2 (partially solved):** During operation on Edit 1, I've tried a code sample from My App, not an entirely new project, the problem was exactly in that code XD. 
Now I've tried other projects and they work.

**Edit 3 (solved):** I'm really sorry, I think you can delete this thread. The logcat was not empty. I had exchanged the position of the logcat screen with the run one, and by force of habit, always clicked on it without reading the label that had changed. Forgive the fool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio allow you to run Stable, Beta and Canary builds at the same time. Try running your app on stable version to find out if this has something to do with the IDE or your app.
When you are running Beta/Canary builds it is always a good idea to keep a stable version in your computer as these releases are not always 100% stable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a noob and I don't knew how to try that. However I've tried to create a new simple project but the result is the same. So the problem is the IDE

Comment: Read Original Post ;-)